# Full-width table

Tags: tables, alignment, fullwidth

I'm trying to make a full page width table with three columns of the same size (33% of the page each). I have done this with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X}`, but I get all the cells with centered text. If I try to align in a different way, I lost the full width property. I need to align left the left cell, center the middle cell and align right the right cell. I read the documentation of `tabularx` package but I can't find the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `X` columns do not centre by default so if that is happening it is due to code you have not shown. Please always include a complete small document that shows the issue which people can debug and use to test answers.

Comment: \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{centering\arraybackslash}X >{raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Even better: He could have used tabulary.

Comment: @Sveinung the op says he wants the X columns _not_ centred (but has given no clues as to how they are centred)

Comment: @JohnKormylo the question is using tabularx so array is assumed.

Comment: @Sveinung - Oops, did not realize tabularx included \RequirePackage{array}.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but both tabularx and tabulary are really nice programs, I recommend both :-)